# Angular js Uncheck checkbox on cancel button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" ng-model="Crate" ng-click="crate('sm',$event)">
```

on model cancel

```
$scope.cancelC = function() {
console.log($scope.Crate); 
}
```

//it showing false but not unchecking the checkbox

Comment: can you copy the method that turns Crate false?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the ng-value. You can use just `ng-value="true"` or other values, as string value `ng-value="'now-this-is-a-string-value'"`.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('TestController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  this.title = 'Test';
  this.value = true;
  this.toggle = function() {
    vm.value = !vm.value;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController as test">
    {{ test.title }}
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" ng-model="test.value" ng-value="true" />
    <button ng-click="test.toggle('sm',$event)">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```